# How to access static class in different file from partial class

Tags: c#, .net, class, static

I have partial class Form1 in Form1.cs .
I have ManagedIpHelper static class in Sample.cs file.

I want to access a method in that static class from a method in Form1 class. But when I use this is showing doesn't exist in the current context.
In both of the file name namespace is same. I have another class named `TcpRow` in the Sample.cs file. It's normal `public class` and it's accessible with no error from Form1's method.

What is suggested solution to this?

**EDIT**

I am sorry.

`TcpRow a;
foreach (TcpRow tcpRow in ManagedIpHelper.GetExtendedTcpTable(true))`

for this code, first line has error `TcpRow could not be found(are you missing a using directive...`
and second line has only error : `ManagedIpHelper` doesn't exist in current context.

**EDIT 2**

sample.cs

[image: sample.cs]

Form1.cs

[image: form1.cs]

Comment: Can you show us a little code, please? (e.g. classes and their methods; where the contents of the methods has been shortened/removed)

Comment: Can you post the namespace declaration of TcpRow, ManagedIpHelper, and Form1?

Comment: @soham.m17 quick sanity check: you have saved and recompiled this in its current form, right?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the indentation and other viewing problem.

Comment: @soham.m17 Are there any other errors, or just these two?

Comment: Just these two errors. No others.

Comment: @soham.m17 I'm out of ideas, without seeing the code in person.

Comment: I feel helpless also. Didn't find any flaws to the code!!

Answer (score 0):

Is the method in the static class `private` or `protected`?  That would cause the method to not be visible.

Comment: Method is public in the static class.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace of your static class is possibly different from the namespace of Form1.Cs, you should make sure that if they are different that you add a using statement to the top of your Form1.cs class.

```
 using NetProject;
```

In addition, to call the static method, you should call it like so.

```
 ManagedHelper.MethodName(....)
```

Your sample.cs file should look like the following.  This code will compile, however it's recommended for you to separate your classes into different files.

**Form1.cs**

```
namespace NetProject
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Form1
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            TcpRow row;

            foreach (TcpRow tcpRow in ManagedIpHelper.GetExtendedTcpTable(true))
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample.cs**

```
namespace NetProject
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class TcpTable : IEnumerable<TcpRow>
    {
        public IEnumerator<TcpRow> GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            // You should implement this method
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class TcpRow
    {

    }

    public static class ManagedIpHelper
    {
        public static TcpTable GetExtendedTcpTable(bool value)
        {
            // You should implement this method
            return new TcpTable();
        }
    }
}
```

Check out the documentation on namespaces at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I have changed the namespace to same. They both have same namespace. Also I am calling the method by ManagedIpHelper.Methodname()

Still, it's showing error.

Comment: You need to add the namespace of TcpRow as well.

Comment: The TcpRow and ManagedIpHelper are in same file sample.cs. and the file has same namespace as the form1.cs has.

Comment: @soham.m17 are either classes *inside* another class, or just directly in the namespace declaration?

Comment: Why should I again import my Form1 in sample.cs? It's already in Form1.cs. sample.cs and Form1.cs has only one namespace NetProject. So, Can you explain?

Comment: If they are separate you should keep them separate.  But this code will compile regardless of whether or not they are in separate .cs files.  I will edit to separate them.

Comment: So, you mean to use a static class I have to use the same file. 

Okay. it's okay for partial class. Let's say if we have to access a static class from a normal public class in different .cs file.
Then?

Comment: And also a problem is that your `SomeMethod` is not accessible from the other .cs file's method.

Comment: The compiler does not care if they are in a separate file or in the same file.  The only thing that should matter in this case is that your class is either #1 in an assembly that your project references or #2 in the same project (for example sample.cs).  I put them in the same file for convience, but I have already changed the code to reflect them being in a separate files and everything still compiles.

Comment: Now, exactly same thing is there for me also. But still it's showing error.

Comment: See, I have given the screenshots for sample.cs and form1.cs respectively. See error marked there.

Comment: Have you checked that the code compiles without Form1?  I think you have an error in TcpRow.